# SAPUI5 Worklist/Demokit application explained - where are the data coming from?

Tags: javascript, orm, odata, sapui5

I am trying to understand Worklist/Demokit application https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/worklist/demokit.html from the source code in SAPUI5 SDK.

But some misunderstanding remains. E.g. where are the data coming from ? In usual Java applications it is clear - where are the service layer with Data Transfer Objects, where are the data repositories, where is the data access layer with ORM mapping and so on. But with this SAPUI5 example those notions seem to be irrelevant ?

I guess that source code should have data initialization code that creates records for Object 1, Object 2 and so on, but I can't find it.

It could be great to have detailed tutorial for this sample application.

Answer (score 1):

The data is a static file as it's just a demo and comes from here: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/worklist/test/service/Objects.json